# 8086 address b800h: writing a symbol directly to video memory with TASM

Tags: memory, video, assembly, x86-16, tasm

I want to write a program for displaying ascii symbols by writing directly to the video memory.

```
.model tiny
.stack
.data
.code
main: 

mov ax, b800h
mov ds, ax

mov aL, 'x'
mov es, bx
mov es:[20], aL

end main
```

I'm getting this error when i try to compile with TASM

```
"Undefined symbol: B800H"
```

Comment: What OS is this for? If it's for DOS you should use an interrupt at the end to exit to DOS: `MOV AH, 4CH` / `INT 21H`

Answer (score 4):

Put a `0` in front of it so TASM can tell it's a numeric value rather than a symbol:

```
mov ax, 0b800h
```

You also appear to be missing anything that will *return* from your program. Without that, it's hard to say *what* code will be run after the `mov es:[20], al`, but I suspect it won't be pretty.

You need something like [int 21, function 4c](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah4c). I've always found [Ralf Brown's interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) to be invaluable for this sort of stuff.

---

You *may* also want to consider the possibility of moving to a tool that's been in active maintenance sometime in the last decade :-)

TASM 5 was released in the 90s and patched up to about 2002, and doesn't support a lot of the new stuff that's been done since then (MMX, SSE and so on). My personal favorite is NASM but there are a number of other options.

Comment: fantastic, but now the .exe hangs indefinitely when i run it, can you see any other problems?

Comment: @user2241226: it's going off into fairy land because you don't return from your program - see the update.

Comment: @user2241226, these are all _different_ problems to the `b800` one. You'll get better use out of SO if you ask them as different questions. Comments aren't really the place to ask more questions unrelated to the original.

Comment: understood, infinite gratitude

Comment: the ralf brown list is fantastic, I wonder why I couldn't find it before

Comment: @user2241226, for the same reason you can't find stuff about heredocs or perlops - you have to know what to look for. Everyone who suffered through early 8086/MSDOS times knows the name Ralf Brown - heck, we near worship him as a deity :-)